# Variable not defined

Tags: matlab, loops, variables

I wanted to run this line but unfortunately it throws an error. Any ideas?

> Undefined function or variable `mr`.
>
> Error in Playground (line 23)
>   `X = min(mr);`

```
j = 1;

for i = 1:(resolution1+1)
    line(i) = m(a(1))*ab(i)+c;
end

for i = 1:(resolution1)
    if or(or(line(i)>ab_y(i) & line(i+1)<ab_y1(i+1),line(i)<ab_y1(i)& line(i+1)>ab_y1(i+1)),line(i)==ab_y1(i))
        mr(j) = ab1(i);
        rk(j) = ab_y1(j);
        j = j+1;
    end
end

X = min(mr);
Y = max(mr);
```

Comment: well, it is defined **only if** `(or(line(i)>ab_y(i) & line(i+1)<ab_y1(i+1),line(i)<ab_y1(i)& line(i+1)>ab_y1(i+1)),line(i)==ab_y1(i)) ` evaluates to 1. When it evaluates to 0, `mr(j)=ab1(i);` isn't executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition:

```
or(or(line(i)>ab_y(i) & line(i+1)<ab_y1(i+1),line(i)<ab_y1(i)& line(i+1)>ab_y1(i+1)),line(i)==ab_y1(i))
```

returns always false, so the statements inside

```
mr(j)=ab1(i); rk(j)=ab_y1(j);
```

are never executed. Therefore variable `mr` does not exist.

Add an `mr = [];` statement before the loop to initialize the variable (and also revise your condition why it returns always false).

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure where the error took place. Thanks for your hint